# ADF Pipeline Errors - RequestContentTooLarge and InvalidContentLink

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

The ADF Pipeline release to the test Data Factory instance is failing with the following error as shown in the image below.

[image]

So, to overcome the above issue, I modified the pipeline by adding an additional step of Azure Blob File Copy to store the linked templates in a storage account and reference it in the pipeline to use it for the deployment. However when I made the above change I am getting another error which states `InvalidContentLink: Unable to download deployment content from 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/adf-arm-templates/ArmTemplate_0.json?***Sanitized Azure Storage Account Shared Access Signature***'. The tracking Id is 'xxxxx-xxxx-x-xxxx-xx'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.`

I have tried using the SAS token for both at the Container level and at the Storage Account level. I also have ensured that the agent and the storage account are under same VNets. I have also tried to remove the firewall restrictions but still it gives me the same `InvalidContentLink` error.

The modified pipeline with the Azure Storage Account step :

[image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidContentLink: Unable to download deployment content from 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/adf-arm-templates/ArmTemplate_0.json?***Sanitized Azure Storage Account Shared Access Signature***'. The tracking Id is 'xxxxx-xxxx-x-xxxx-xx'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

- This error can cause because of you are trying to link   which might not present in storage account.
- Make sure you provide correct URl for the nested template that is accessible.
- Also, if your storage account has firewall rule you can't link nested template from it.
  [image]
- Make sure your Storage Account, Container and Blob are publicly available. To achieve this:
  Provide a Blob level Shared Access Signature URL. select the file click on"`...`" and then Click on Generate SAS.
  [image]

refer for more understanding about [nested template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell).

Comment: The storage account URI is accessible. I tried using both - a storage account with firewall and without firewall. Also there are more than 40 linked templates so I cannot possibly generate SAS at the blob level for each of these templates and set the parameter value in the main template